# using data file pulled using awk for sed command on another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to return data which occurs on specific lines in one file, and use those lines to return the data from another file on those same lines.  I have been looking through the notes online here, and have found something i thought would work.  However i am getting an error currently.  any suggestions?

`file1` has the values `1 2 3`

`file2` has the values `three four five`

so the output should be `three`

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '/one/ {print NR}'  file1>fileonehold
filename="fileonehold"
while read -r line
do
    sed -n ${line}p file2 >> file2hold
done < "$fileonehold"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then the most straightforward way is to use awk:

```
awk -v pattern="one" 'NR == FNR && $0 ~ pattern { a[FNR] = 1 } NR != FNR && a[FNR]' file1 file2
```

This works as follows: `-v pattern="one"` makes known to awk a variable named `pattern` whose value is `one`. Then the code is

```
NR == FNR && $0 ~ pattern {  # if we're still processing the first file (file1),
                             # and if the current line matches the pattern
  a[FNR] = 1                 # remember that line number.
}
NR != FNR && a[FNR]          # if we're not processing the first file and the
                             # current line number is a remembered one, print.
```

The core trick here is the condition `NR == FNR` (and `NR != FNR`). `NR` is the number of records (lines, by default) processed so far, `FNR` is the number of records processed so far from the current file. These are equal when processing the first file from the command line but not afterwards.<sup>1</sup>

Apart from that: the condition `NR != FNR && a[FNR]` does not have an associated action, so the default action (printing) is performed if it is true. `a[FNR]` is true only for marked lines because the default value (an empty string) is considered false and `1` (the marker value) is considered true by awk.

<sup>1</sup> unless the first file is empty, in which case the code will still not print anything.

Comment: Sorry just updated the question, I only want to return values on lines in the second file based on a specific value found in the first file, i.e. if i search the value 2 in file one, it returns line 2, and then i use that line to get four from file2.

Comment: See the edit. Note that the files are processed the other way around for this one.